# Unity is saying Audioclip is null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using this script to try and pull random noises to play during gameplay

```
    public class Sons : MonoBehaviour
    {
    public static AudioClip al1, al2, al3, al4, al5, al6, al7, al8, al9, al10, al11, al12, al13;
    static AudioSource Audio;
    int randomizer;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
        randomizer = (Random.Range(1, 13));
        //sons aleatorios=============================================================
        al1 = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("ran1");
        al2 = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("ran2");
        al3 = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("ran3");
        al4 = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("ran4");
        al5 = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("ran5");
        al6 = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("ran6");
        al7 = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("ran7");
        al8 = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("ran8");
        al9 = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("ran9");
        al10 = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("ran10");
        al11 = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("ran11");
        al12 = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("ran12");
        al13 = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("ran13");

        InvokeRepeating("RNDSND", 1f, 20f);
        //sons ventilação============================================================

        //sons corredor==============================================================

        //sons salas=================================================================

        Audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

      }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    void RNDSND()
    {
        switch (randomizer)
        {
            case 1:
                Audio.PlayOneShot(al1);
                 break;
            case 2:
                Audio.PlayOneShot(al2);
                break;
            case 3:
                Audio.PlayOneShot(al3);
                break;
            case 4:
                Audio.PlayOneShot(al4);
                break;
            case 5:
                Audio.PlayOneShot(al5);
                break;
            case 6:
                Audio.PlayOneShot(al6);
                break;
            case 7:
                Audio.PlayOneShot(al7);
                break;
            case 8:
                Audio.PlayOneShot(al8);
                break;
            case 9:
                Audio.PlayOneShot(al9);
                break;
            case 10:
                Audio.PlayOneShot(al10);
                break;
            case 11:
                Audio.PlayOneShot(al11);
                break;
            case 12:
                Audio.PlayOneShot(al12);
                break;
            case 13:
                Audio.PlayOneShot(al13);
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

...but unity sends the message "PlayOneShot Was Called With Null AudioClip"

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong and any possible solutions?

Comment: Which play one shot is null? One of those al variables is null.

Comment: Use a debugger. Put a breakpoint on the `InvokeRepeating` line in `Start` and examine those variables to see which one didn't load. You could also add a check after each one and log which ones are NULL. It would be much easier to do if you used an array and a loop to load them. That would make the play logic much simpler too. You probably want the random value to be picked inside `RNDSND` unless you want to play the same sound every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend doing something more like this:

```
public class Sons : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip[] randSounds;
    static AudioSource Audio;
    int randomizer;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < randSounds.Length; i++)
        {
            randSounds[i] = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("ran" + i);
        }

        Audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        InvokeRepeating("RNDSND", 1f, 20f);
    }

    void RNDSND()
    {
        randomizer = (Random.Range(0, randSounds.Length));
        Audio.PlayOneShot(randSounds[randomizer]);        
    }
}
```

Untested. I would probably also just delete the `Resources.Load` call since it seems expensive memory wise to do that on load for all your objects, you probably want to assign those clips into the inspector if possible, or load them on `Awake()` and before you need to use them.